# Are the sums equal to each other?

Tags: integration, trigonometry, logarithms

They are $2$ different results for the integral 
$$\int xe^{2x}\sin\left(\frac x3\right)\,dx$$

1. $\displaystyle\frac{-3}{1369}e^{2x}\left(3(35-74x)\sin\left(\frac x3\right)+(37x-36)\cos\left(\frac x3\right) \right)$
2. $\displaystyle\frac{3}{37}e^{2x}\left(x\left(6\sin\left(\frac x3\right)-\cos\left(\frac x3\right) \right) -\frac{3}{37}\left(35\sin\left(\frac x3\right)-13\cos\left(\frac x3\right)  \right)\right) $

Are the sums equal to each other?

Comment: if their derivatives really are the same, they differ by a constant at worst. The constant can be evaluated, say, with $x=0$ if everything else checks out.

Comment: According to Wolfram Alpha, they are equal: http://goo.gl/iBLs8f

Comment: Look pretty good by eye, the main points being $74 = 2 \cdot 37$ and $37^2 = 1369.$ I suggest you multiply both out, everything is a multiple of $3 e^{2x} / 37,$ after pulling that you have coefficients for 4 basic terms.

Comment: 2nd equation should be -12cos(x/3)

Answer (score 2):

Second equation:

$$\frac{3}{1369}e^{2x}(37(6x\sin(x/3)-x\cos(x/3))-3(35\sin(x/3)-12\cos(x/3))$$

$$=\frac{3}{1369}e^{2x}(222x\sin(x/3)-37x\cos(x/3)-105\sin(x/3)+36\cos(x/3))$$

$$=\frac{3}{1369}e^{2x}(3(74x-34)\sin(x/3)-37x\cos(x/3)+36\cos(x/3))$$

$$=\frac{-3}{1369}e^{2x}(3(34-74x)\sin(x/3)+(37x-36)\cos(x/3))$$

So they are equal.

Answer (score 2):

@Samir;

Set them equal to each other and divide both sides by e^(2x).

$ -\frac{3 \left((-36+37 x) \cos \left(\frac{x}{3}\right)+3 (35-74 x) \sin \left(\frac{x}{3}\right)\right)}{1369}=\frac{3}{37} \left(x \left(-\cos \left(\frac{x}{3}\right)+6 \sin \left(\frac{x}{3}\right)\right)-\frac{3}{37} \left(-12 \cos \left(\frac{x}{3}\right)+35 \sin \left(\frac{x}{3}\right)\right)\right) $

Multiply both sides by 1369.

$-3 \left((-36+37 x) \cos \left(\frac{x}{3}\right)+3 (35-74 x) \sin \left(\frac{x}{3}\right)\right)=111 \left(x \left(-\cos \left(\frac{x}{3}\right)+6 \sin \left(\frac{x}{3}\right)\right)-\frac{3}{37} \left(-12 \cos \left(\frac{x}{3}\right)+35 \sin \left(\frac{x}{3}\right)\right)\right) $

Divide both sides by 3.

$ -(-36+37 x) \cos \left(\frac{x}{3}\right)-3 (35-74 x) \sin \left(\frac{x}{3}\right)=37 \left(x \left(-\cos \left(\frac{x}{3}\right)+6 \sin \left(\frac{x}{3}\right)\right)-\frac{3}{37} \left(-12 \cos \left(\frac{x}{3}\right)+35 \sin \left(\frac{x}{3}\right)\right)\right) $

Start cleaning up.

$ (36-37 x) \cos \left(\frac{x}{3}\right)-(105-222 x) \sin \left(\frac{x}{3}\right)=37 \left(x \left(-\cos \left(\frac{x}{3}\right)+6 \sin \left(\frac{x}{3}\right)\right)-\frac{3}{37} \left(-12 \cos \left(\frac{x}{3}\right)+35 \sin \left(\frac{x}{3}\right)\right)\right) $

$ (36-37 x) \cos \left(\frac{x}{3}\right)-(105-222 x) \sin \left(\frac{x}{3}\right)=37 \left(-x \cos \left(\frac{x}{3}\right)+6 x \sin \left(\frac{x}{3}\right)-\frac{3}{37} \left(-12 \cos \left(\frac{x}{3}\right)+35 \sin \left(\frac{x}{3}\right)\right)\right) $

$ (36-37 x) \cos \left(\frac{x}{3}\right)-(105-222 x) \sin \left(\frac{x}{3}\right)=-37 x \cos \left(\frac{x}{3}\right)+222 x \sin \left(\frac{x}{3}\right)-3 \left(-12 \cos \left(\frac{x}{3}\right)+35 \sin \left(\frac{x}{3}\right)\right) $

$ (36-37 x) \cos \left(\frac{x}{3}\right)-(105-222 x) \sin \left(\frac{x}{3}\right)=36 \cos \left(\frac{x}{3}\right)-37 x \cos \left(\frac{x}{3}\right)-105 \sin \left(\frac{x}{3}\right)+222 x \sin \left(\frac{x}{3}\right) $

$ 36 \cos \left(\frac{x}{3}\right)-37 x \cos \left(\frac{x}{3}\right)-(105-222 x) \sin \left(\frac{x}{3}\right)=36 \cos \left(\frac{x}{3}\right)-37 x \cos \left(\frac{x}{3}\right)-105 \sin \left(\frac{x}{3}\right)+222 x \sin \left(\frac{x}{3}\right) $

Easy to see now that they are equal.